# Redefinition of equals()

Tags: java

This is an extract from Core Java by C. Horstmann.
+++++
The hashCode method should return an integer (which can be negative). Just combine the
hash codes of the instance fields so that the hash codes for different objects are likely to
be widely scattered.
For example, here is a hashCode method for the Employee class:

```
class Employee
{
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return 7 * name.hashCode() + 11 * new Double(salary).hashCode() + 13 * hireDay.hashCode();
    }
. . .
}
```

+++

I can't understand these 7, 11, and 13. Are they just pulled out of a hat? Without them the result (checking for equality of two objects) seems to be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the numbers are prime numbers.

you don't want to just add the hash codes, because it would give you more collissions.

e.g.

situation A: foo="bla", bar="111"

situation B: foo="111", bar="bla"

this means that `foo.hash() + bar.hash()` will return the same value in both situations. you use prime numbers because the function f: N/2^32 -> N/2^32: x -> x * p (mod 2^32)  is bijective if p is a prime > 2. (i.e. you would lose bits if you multiplied with 256 instead...)

collisions are only to be avoided if you use somthing like hash-sets.

Answer (score 3):

In general, testing for equality does not use the hash code.

The 7, 11, 13 are all prime numbers. This lowers the possibility of two different employees having the same hash code (because of [theorem of Bézout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem)).

<sup>In fact, I would suggest (to widen the obtained hash) using much bigger but non-consecutive primes, e.g.  1039, 2011, 32029. On Linux, the `/usr/games/primes` utility from package `bsdgames` is very useful to get them.</sup>

What is important is that if two things compare equal they have the same hash code.
For perfomance reasons, you want the hash code to be widely distributed (so if two things are not equals, their hash code usually should be different) to lower the probability of [hash collision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_%28computer_science%29).

Read wikipage on [hash tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying with primes is a common optimization which is often done for you by your IDE. I wouldn't do it if there is no need for optimization.

Comment: its not an optimization ;)

Comment: No, collisions are much more probable without such multiplications!

Comment: Collisions are not a problem if you don't need to optimize. I get why this is done in libs and frameworks, but for teaching the concept of the hashcode/equals contract and for most of the applications out there an unoptimized hashcode will have zero implications. Especially in the given example (out of a book) it's plain stupid to multiply with primes because it confuses the reader.

Comment: I disagree. Collision is central to the concept of hash tables. Conveying the message that an hash function should be carefully chosen and widely distributed is essential in any good algorithmic book (and linear combination with prime coefficients is a useful trick, to be known by every coder).

Comment: Yeah of course. Thousands of applications are going down each day because of a simple (but correct) hash code every day. Haven't seen weird bugs with *wrong* equals/hashcode implementations, however. As you say, it's a useful trick which should be known by experienced devs. But it's a *trick*.

Comment: I think the misunderstanding here is wether you regard 'making a hash-function more collission-resistant' an "optimization" or a "code improvement beyond mere optimization". I think this is more a question of programmer personality than a technical one, so I don't want to argue for any of the two sides. I wouldn't call it an optimization, but I can understand if someone else does.

Comment: Well it depends so much on the context. If your doing some high load calculation math whatever stuff, this may be important. For your **FooManagementSystem** it is most definitely not. Now guess what most java devs are building.